# Google appengine Cloud integration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I have created a Google App Engine project  with  new https://console.developers.google.com/project/ and after that I try to activate Cloud integration to have Cloud storage default bucket but I always have the response

> An error occurred when creating the project. Please retry.

The error persist since yesterday, it could be an error on google cloud system?

Regards.

Comment: It seems that google has just chage it policy and now  it needs to enable billing to activate this options while last week I have create a project withou this restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Storage always required billing enabled on the project. While the error message could be clearer at this point, if you follow the steps to "enable google cloud storage" in the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/signup#activate), the 4th step points out you need to enable billing

With further research, I found that there is currently [an issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12140) with Cloud Integration (actually [two](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?can=2&q=12138)) that could explain why Cloud Integration is not exactly working as expected at the moment.

Comment: I have created many project activating cloud integration without billing until this week

Comment: hmmm... possible that the previous projects didn't have an App Engine component, therefore the cloud storage bucket wasn't created.

Comment: I try to activate the option before and after deploy an version, the 1 of July I have already create an application and activate It in the same way and works correctly but it fails this time. Regards any way

Comment: @Quizh I actually found this https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12140 that might explain the problem you've had :)

Comment: Finally I activate the billing and the proccess works.